# Как правильно сделать переадресацию по кукам?

Tags: php, cookie

Всем привет, такая проблема, на сайте есть 2 языка /md/ и /ru/, при открытии сайта по умолчанию открывается молдавская версия. Переключая язык, ссылка становится: site.ru/ru/ на русскую версию, соответственно если переключить на другой язык, то будет: site.ru/md/

Я хочу запоминать язык пользователя в куках, который он выберет и в дальнейшем, когда он будет заходить на сайт - делать переадресацию на нужный язык.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ru') !== false) {
        setcookie("lang", "ru", (time()+9999999));
    } else {
        setcookie("lang", "md", (time()+9999999));
    }

    if($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'ru') {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ru') === false) {
            $this->response->redirect('/ru')->send();
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'md') === false) {
            $this->response->redirect('/md')->send();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Вот как я это сделал, но у меня это не работает и выдает ошибку "переадресация выполнена слишком много раз", может у кого-то есть идеи? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ф12 в браузере Сеть откройте, и посмотрите откуда куда ваш запрос пересылается. У вас там редиректы зацикливаются, вот и выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: да по всей видимости с молдавского у вас переключает на русский - получаем страницу и она видит о - русский надо переключить на молдавский - и пошло бесконечное зацикливание переходов - вам видимо надо отрубить это автоматическое переключение